# Python - Flask - Bootstrap. Quick & automatic way to edit template links?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Well I know to add a bootstrap theme I need to go through the templates or .htm pages and edit URLs using `url_for()` function. I think editing URLs in large htm templates is kinda tedious and time wasting process. So is there any tricky way to edit htm templates quickly? Any kind of extension or plugin can do this automatically? Or even any special software to easily and quickly edit links?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I've just done this using Material Design for Bootstrap. Your templates will have to import the assets from the Bootstrap package. (The CSS, JS etc.) From there you can edit your templates to use the classes from Bootstrap.

As for the URLs, it sounds like you already have templates made with URLs in them. I think the fastest way to change these templates to fit the Jinja2 syntax would be to open them in your favorite editor and use the Find and Replace feature. Have it find the URLs you wish to replace with `url_for()` blocks and replace them in sets. Of course, this only helps if you have repeating URLs. Otherwise, you might as well do them manually to be more thorough.

A snippet from my templates:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="../static/css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And one of my URLs:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link animated fadeInDown" href="{{('dashboard')"}}></a>
      </li>
```

Comment: Actually I downloaded one bootstrap website. Now trying to use it as website interface. So you mean till now there is no automated process for this. Find and replace is fine and I know this of course. But I was looking for automatic route. Thanks for you answer though. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Flask-Bootstrap extension -
 https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/?

Comment: I heard of it and visited your link but didnt understand! Is it used to add bootstrap web templates or to create websites from the scratch using bootstrap? If you can then explain how the extension works in my case.